# Using query string in ASP (vb script)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a form named form-web.asp and the action of the form is web-process.asp. Basically users are accessing the form while adding a name and surname as parameters. ex **/form-web.asp?name=tyron&surname=vella** . In the web-process.asp I want to get these values.

How I can do this please?

Answer (score 3):

Use hidden form controls to store the values which you want to forward to web-process.asp:

```
<%
Dim name, surname
name = Request.QueryString("name")
surname = Request.QueryString("surname")
' Do whatever other input validation you need
%>
<form action="web-process.asp">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(name) %>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(surname) %>" />
</div>
</form>
```

"Hidden" controls won't be displayed, but will still be submitted with the form.

Comment: You actually noticed something subtle that the other two answerers did not notice, hence the hidden fields in your answer. I'm not 100% sure the OP meant to write the question like he did, but +1 for noticing and answering to that.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your URL is

```
ex/form-web.asp?name=tyron&surname=vella
```

than try something like this,

```
Hi, <%=Request.QueryString("name")%> <%= Request.QueryString("age")%>
```

output

```
Hi, tyron vella
```

Answer (score 1):

Request.QueryString is what you are looking for. It returns a value from the querystring.

For example: /form-web.asp?name=tyron&surname=vella

```
Request.QueryString("name")
```

would give you 'tyron'